Gitlab: Merge Request Keeps Autofilling
I have a condition when I request a new merge, the Title and Description field is automatically filled. When I looked it up, it was from the Local Storage. But when I deleted it, it persisted after refresh.

I believe this happened after I reverted a commit to the previous one. How can I manage to resolve this? Thank you.

Title and description are autofilled from the commit message when the MR contains only one commit.

Yes, I do know so. But, the auto-filled title and description are just same everytime I do MR

You can simply remove the description and change the title then click on create request, once the page is reloaded it will again persists the same autofilled value because gitlab description and title internally works that way to help others avoid writing these description and title.
Make sure if you change the description or title then you don't refresh the page.
